# Android SDK Instance error when launching emulator

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have Visual Studio 2019 installed with all updates. I decided to install Mobile Development feature for Android.

All got installed and i created my first app by selecting Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms) for C# and unticked iPhone.

When i click the icon to run the app I see the below image. I click Open Installer and then search for "Android" but it seems the SDK is already installed.

[image]

What else do i require to get this working?

Edit 1 - I have also attached my locations on this image just in case this might cause a twist somehow

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running as a standard user on Windows 10. Logging in with an administrator account first time round allowed the initial configuration to be carried out. Once this was ok i returned back as a standard user and all was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check `Android SDK Location` is set correctly.

You could find it `Options- Xamarin - Android -Android SDK Location` .

[image]

Comment: Thanks - that was correct but for info i was running as a standard user. I swapped to an administrator and it worked. Finally swapping back to my standard user